# Need to Show a gif on button click

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, button

I am working in Unbounce. I want a gif of a spinner to be hidden, but show when the user clicks the button. I have a button labeled `#lp-pom-button-279` and an image labeled `#lp-pom-image-288`

I tried using JS and CSS to hide/show the gif but for some reason I only see it hidden or completely shown – it doesn't load on click.

```
<script>
  $('#lp-pom-button-279').click(function() {
  $('#lp-pom-image-288').show(); //<----here
  $.ajax({
    ....
    success: function(result) {
      $('#spinner').hide();  //<--- hide again
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  #lp-pom-image-288 {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: #spinner is not your #lp-pom-image-288?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use ajax to simply hide an image. First, you have to hide the picture and on button click, you show it.

You can solve this problem with the jQuery function [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)/[show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) or change the style with the jQuery [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function.

> with hide() and show()

```js
$('#picture').hide(); // hide at beginning

$('#button').click(function(){
  $('#picture').show(); // show on button click
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Show picture</button>
<br />
<img id="picture" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"/>
```

> with css()

```js
$('#picture').css("display", "none"); // hide at beginning

$('#button').click(function(){
  $('#picture').css("display", "block"); // show button on click
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Show picture</button>
<br />
<img id="picture" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the spinner with wrong id.

```
success:function(result){
       $('#lp-pom-image-288').hide();  //<--- hide again
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` you use in your `success` callback function is wrong:

```js
$('#lp-pom-button-279').click(function() {
  $('#lp-pom-image-288').show(); // <- Show spinner here
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users',
    success: function(result) {
      $('#lp-pom-image-288').hide(); // <- Hide spinner here
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#lp-pom-image-288 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="lp-pom-button-279">Button</button>
<div id="lp-pom-image-288">Spinner</div>
```